# Compare two Views in SQL Server and and create a gen Table

Tags: sql-server, view

I did create two VIEWS in SQL Server

VIEW 1

`NameID        1 2 3 4
 Name          A B C D`

View 2:

`SoftwareID        1 2 3 4 5 6 7

 NameID            1 1 1 3 3 2 2`

I want to create a Gentable from the Views like this

`NameID        1       2    3    4

 SoftwareID    1,2,3,  6,7  4,5  NULL`

I want to denormalize the data. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very messy and thrown together but this will give you what you want:

```
select distinct
v.NameID,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(SoftwareID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
         FROM @view2 
         WHERE NameID = t.NameID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
from View2 t
right join View1 v on t.NameID = v.NameID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp')IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp
;With View1(NameID,Name)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'C' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'D' 
)
,View2(SoftwareID,NameID)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1UNion all
SELECT 2,1UNion all
SELECT 3,1UNion all
SELECT 4,3UNion all
SELECT 5,3UNion all
SELECT 6,2UNion all
SELECT 7,2
)
,Final
AS
(
SELECT v1.NameID,v2.SoftwareID from View1 v1
LEFT join View2 v2
On v1.NameID=v2.NameID
)
SELECT DISTINCT o.NameID,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+CAST(i.SoftwareID AS VARCHAR(5))
From Final i  WHERE i.NameID=o.NameID FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS SoftwareID
FROM Final  o
```

OutPut

```
NameID  SoftwareID
-------------------
1       1,2,3
2       6,7
3       4,5
4       NULL
```